# Factorisation of large polynomials and Galois theory

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, factoring

As I understand it, one of the consequences of Galois theory is that there is no way of expressing the solutions to a general polynomial of degree 5 or higher in terms of radicals. Would a theory that can produce a way of expressing the solutions to a polynomial under specific restrictive conditions contradict this theory, or would that be a loophole of some kind?

I have thought of a method of factoring large polynomials that requires the roots to have certain properties and it makes sense, on a basic level, but I would like to know if it can actually work for large polynomials.

EDIT 1:

$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

$f(x) = [a, b, c].[x^2, x, 1]$

the two vectors are orthogonal when $f(x) = 0$
there are two vectors were they are orthogonal
the cross product of those two vectors will give an vector perpendicular to $[a, b, c]$
this gives 3 equations and 3 variables to solve.

The concept is that for an $n$ degree polynomial it is possible to create $n-1$ vectors in $R^n$ that can be placed in a matrix with row one containing unit vectors, solve for the determinant of the matrix, produce n sets of linear equations with n variables, including the spacial variable, and n equations. The variables can then be solved using the simultaneous equations if there are no repeated roots or a solution at zero.

If there is a solution at zero then the determinant has a zero column and is therefore zero and the set of solutions cannot be found with this method.

If there is a repeated root to the polynomial then there are two rows that are equal and a single row addition can give a zero row, and therefore the determinant of the system is zero and the set of solutions cannot be found with this method.

EDIT 2:

a cubic function would look something like this:

$$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$f(x) = [a,b,c,d].[x^3,x^2,x,1]$$

has solutions say, s, t and r then we can write three solutions

$$0 = [a,b,c,d].[s^3,s^2,s,1]$$
$$0 = [a,b,c,d].[t^3,t^2,t,1]$$
$$0 = [a,b,c,d].[r^3,r^2,r,1]$$

finding a vector orthogonal to these three vectors can be done by generalizing the cross product to higher dimensions and finding the determinant:

\begin{array}{cccccc}
i & j & k & l \\
s^3 & s^2 & s & 1 \\
t^3 & t^2 & t & 1 \\
r^3 & r^2 & r & 1\\ 
\end{array}

the determinant of this matrix is then parallel to the vector that they are all each orthogonal to, ie: the vector or the coefficients $[a,b,c,d]$ so we can say that it is equal to $\lambda [a,b,c,d]$, expanding the determinant then gives four equations and four variables, s,t,r and $\lambda$

Comment: The emphasis on that consequence of Galois theory is on a *general* polynomial. We can surely write the zeros of, say $x^5-2$, using radicals. Also, we have no problems whatsoever jotting down the lowest degree polynomial with integer coefficients that has a number given in terms of radicals, say $\root5\of2+\sqrt2$, as one of its zeros. But it is always nice to have inventive methods for constructing examples of many kinds. Can you tell us more? Anyway, a specific family of polynomials with zeros expressible in terms of radicals does not contradict Galois theory. No matter its degree.

Comment: After reading the latter part of your Question in greater detail, it seems the introductory paragraph about Galois theory is not much relevant to what you want to ask about.  You have not made clear what *matrix* you would study in connection with a general $n$th degree polynomial.  Even if the roots of a polynomial are distinct, it is not possible to find all of them as you propose by performing arithmetic on a set of real vectors because linear equations in real coefficients have real solutions, while the polynomial roots will in general be complex.

Comment: I would say compute some examples with roots you know and see what happens. Looks like an interesting problem!

Comment: trouble is that when you get to quintic functions, the ones I am interested in as they appear to somewhat contradict Galois, to compute the determinant there are 6! terms in all of the simultaneous equations, so finding them is difficult, let alone solving them(by hand anyway, and my programming skills are lacking for something like this.). I and use it to solve for quadratics and the answer that got made sense. I want to know if the abstraction can be made for higher dimensions. thinking about it solving the equations might give roots in terms of logs rather than radicals in some instances.

Comment: thinking about it, a proof that this DOESN'T work would also be incredibly interesting to be because on the surface it seems to make sense that it should work.